# Como criar backups de um projeto no Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Não achei uma opção de salvar como   e tentei copiar a pasta inteira mas como o projeto  gera arquivos com o nome muito grande acaba dando erro no windows na hora em que faço a copia pelo ctrl C ctrl V  da pasta inteira ....

Comment: Não é mais fácil criar um repositório ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fala Linkon,

A melhor maneira é criar um repositório online mesmo, os mais usados para projetos Androis são o GitHub e o Bitbucket, segue os links:

GitHub: https://github.com/

BitBucket: https://bitbucket.org/

É bem fácil de usa-los, existem bastante tutoriais na internet, e eles salvam seu projeto por inteiro, sendo só necessário clonar e importar no seu Android Studio depois.

Qualquer dúvida me avisa por inbox que te ajudo.

Abraços.

Comment: Valeu Leonardo! , eu até tenho o github  mas ainda nao mexi nele ahahah vou dar  uma olhada lá,